# How to insert "empty" row extracting a month list?

Tags: sql-server

I've this sp, which return a list of data, for each "month" (i.e. each row is a month). Somethings like that:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    (CAST(t1.NumActivities AS DECIMAL) / t1.NumVisits) * 100 AS PercAccepted,
    (CAST(t1.Accepted AS DECIMAL) / t1.Estimated) * 100 AS PercValue
FROM
    (SELECT
        MONTH(DateVisit) AS Month, 
        COUNT(*) AS NumVisits,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DateActivity is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NumActivities,
        SUM(Estimate) AS Estimated,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DateActivity is not null THEN Estimate ELSE 0 END) AS Accepted
    FROM [dbo].[Activities]
    WHERE 
        DateVisit IS NOT NULL 
        AND (@year IS NULL OR YEAR(DateVisit) = @year) 
        AND (@clinicID IS NULL OR ClinicID = @clinicID)
    GROUP BY MONTH(DateVisit)) t1
```

This is a result:

```
Month   NumVisits   NumActivities   Estimated       Accepted        PercAccepted        PercValue
1       5           1               13770.00        2520.00         20.00000000000      18.30065359477124
2       2           2               7900.00         7900.00         100.00000000000     100.00000000000000
3       1           0               2730.00         0.00            0.00000000000       0.00000000000000
8       1           1               3000.00         3000.00         100.00000000000     100.00000000000000
```

But as you can see, I could "miss" some Month (for example, here April "4" is missed).

Is it possible to insert, for the missing month/row, an empty (0) record? Such as:

```
Month   NumVisits   NumActivities   Estimated       Accepted        PercAccepted        PercValue
1       5           1               13770.00        2520.00         20.00000000000      18.30065359477124
2       2           2               7900.00         7900.00         100.00000000000     100.00000000000000
3       1           0               2730.00         0.00            0.00000000000       0.00000000000000
4       0           0               0               0               0                   0
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a example with sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #Report
(
  Id INT,
  Name nvarchar(max),
  Percentage float
)

INSERT INTO #Report VALUES (1,'ONE',2.01)
INSERT INTO #Report VALUES (2,'TWO',3.01)
INSERT INTO #Report VALUES (5,'Five',5.01)

;WITH months(Month) AS
(
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Month+1 
    FROM months
    WHERE Month < 12
)
SELECT *
INTO #AllMonthsNumber
from months;
```

Your select query:

```
The left join will gives you the NULL for other months so just use ISNULL('ColumnName','String_to_replace')
              \/\/\/\/
SELECT Month, ISNULL(Name,0), ISNULL(Percentage,0)
FROM AllMonthsNumber A 
LEFT JOIN #Report B
ON A.Month = B.Id
```

**EDIT:**

Yes you can do it without creating AllMonthNumber Table:

You can use `master..spt_values` ([*found here*](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/697f4ee6-35d1-403d-a9f7-caecaf1ba479/all-monthnames-and-month-numbers-in-sql-server?forum=transactsql)) system table which contains the numbers so just with some *where* condition.

```
SELECT Number as Month, ISNULL(B.Name,0), ISNULL(Percentage,0)
FROM master..spt_values A 
LEFT JOIN #Report B ON A.Number = B.Id
WHERE Type = 'P' AND number BETWEEN 1 AND 12
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you are suggesting.

Comment: Is it possible to doing this without creating a dedicated AllMonthsNumber table?